# change class on image for image map

Tags: javascript, jquery, sprite, imagemap

I am aware that a lot of similar questions has been asked on this matter, however I seem to not be able to put any of the solutions to use.. 
i have this imagemap located in a div: (never mind the coords - they are not correct right now)

```
<div class="spinner">
 <img src="test.gif"  alt="spinner" id="map" class="map" usemap="#spinnermap">

 <map name="spinnermap">
   <area shape="poly" coords="0,0,82,126" href="" id="systemmap" alt="System">
   <area shape="poly" coords="90,58,3" href="" id="rolemap" alt="Role">
   <area shape="poly" coords="124,58,8" href="" id="phasemap" onclick="createTable();" alt="Phase">
 </map>
</div>
```

Now, when the last poly is clicked (or any, but just for e.g) i need the map img to have a different css class - so that class="map" is replaced by class="phasemap". (I have a sprite for this in the css, you see :))

I have tried this:

```
$('#phasemap').click(function(){
    $(this).find("#map").toggleClass('phasemap map');
});
```

But it doesn't seem to do the trick.. I am sure I have a typo or more - I am very new to this js/jq thingy :)

Edit: I just realized that maybe it means something that the map is created in JS.. So i kinda also need to know where to put the jq stuff (below the map or where in the .js file do i stick this? :))

my JS:

```
function createSpinner() {
    var spinner = '<div class="spinner">';
    spinner += '<img src="filler.png" id="map" class="map" alt="Spinner"  Usemap="#spinnermap" border="0" />';

    spinner += '<map name="spinnermap">';
    spinner += '<area shape="poly" coords="5,25 51,60 110,25 51,2 8,25" href="#" onclick="createTable();" alt="Role">';
    spinner += '<area shape="poly" coords="5,25 8,66, 15,89 55,112 55,66 5,25"  href="#" onclick="createTable();" alt="System">';
    spinner += '<area shape="poly" coords="55,112 89,108 118,59 110,25 51,66 55,112" id="phasemap" href="#" onclick="createTable();" alt="Phase">';
    spinner += '</map>';
    spinner += '</div>';

    return spinner;
}

$('#phasemap').click( function() {
    $("#map").toggleClass('phasemap map');
    return false;
});
```

and the css:

```
.map {
    width: 117px;
    height: 119px;
    background: url('spinner.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.rolemap {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}   

.systemmap {
    background-position: 0px -124px;
}

.phasemap {
    background-position: 0px -248px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hav to use `$('#map')` as `selector` not `$(this).find("#map")` as your `img` is outside of the `phasemap`
Try this,

```
$('#phasemap').click(function(){
   $("#map").toggleClass('phasemap map');
   // Use #map directly it is not children of #phasemap
});// don't use colon here
```

**Updated,** you have to use `return false;` after `toggleClass` to prevent default working of `area` like,

```
$('#phasemap').click(function(){
   $("#map").toggleClass('phasemap map');
   return false;// use return false or event.preventDefault() here
});
```

In the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JW3ff/)** you can see in `console` the `image class` is `toggling`.

From you `edited question` you should use `jquery version >= 1.9` an use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) like,

```
$(document).on('click','#phasemap',function(){
   $("#map").toggleClass('phasemap map');
   return false;
});
```

And you to check `createSpinner()` works or not. by inspecting it in `firebug`

Comment: Hi! thanks - i tried it but it does not work.. (the colon was just a typo in here - but good heads up though :o) )

Comment: i am having js create the areamap - maybe i am placing the toggleClass thing in the wrong place? (yep - did also close the div - thanks for that :o))

Comment: could you please see my edited question and see if I am doing anything in the JS that could cause the JQ to not work ? :) pretty please

Comment: @Sally now check my answer

Comment: createSpinner works - the only thing not working is the toggleClass :) let me just try the on() ..brb

Comment: hi.. i updated the jquery however your code snippet still does not seem to do anything at all..  the map works and the bg image works and the onclick even works, but the class does not change.. :/ am I putting the snippet in the correct place? where would you place it?

Comment: this actually works when used as onclick function.. but since i already have one of those for each maparea??

Comment: it also works if I skip all kinds of onclick, however i need the script to do bot the onclick and the class change.. i really don't understand where to put this thing :/

Answer (score 0):

```
var a=0;
function yourfunctionname(){
  if(a == 0){
   $("#map").attr('class','');
   $("#map").attr('class','phasemap map');
   a=1;
   return false;
  }
  else{
   $("#map").attr('class','');
   $("#map").attr('class','map');
   a=0;
   return false;
   }
 // your function code 
}
```

Comment: hi! is this supposed to be an onclick function?

Comment: but... i already have an onclick.. i don't think you are allowed more than one?

Comment: you can add more than one if you want to use with you already have function then no need to call an another function but inside part you just need to copy in your present function at the top... your problem will be solved .. gud luck sally

Comment: so.. a function in a function?

Comment: how do I add an extra onclick??

Comment: i updated my code it will help you dear, also it is the easiest way to do it

Comment: thanks for trying - it does not work - only one function is executed :/

Comment: remove return false and than again try